# Is there any web automation testing tool to test fonts, alignment, spacing, cross browser, styles, etc

Tags: cross-browser, automated-tests, alignment, font-size, spacing

I am currently working in an organization where they are delivering the websites in a week or two. The organization has its in build components created on Drupal. The developers only take the modules and integrate it with new site.

As a QA we just need to verify the alignments, fonts, spacing, Cross browsers, Responsiveness, etc.

Is there any automation tool available in market to do so.

I am looking for a name of software. If there is any kind of software available then provide the link.

NA

Comment: By using Selenium WebDriver it could be done. You can use java, python or other programming language with Selenium WD to customize your test script to do so.